# Unable to open specific view depending on whether it was opened through a push notification or not?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to open a different view in my app depending on whether it was opened via a push notification or not. Here is the code I have so far:

AppDelegate:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AppState()
    @Published var pageToNavigationTo : String?
}


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    @Published var openedFromNotification: Bool = false
    @Published var isFromNotification = false

    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.Message_ID"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        openedFromNotification = true
        
        if launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] != nil {
            openedFromNotification = true
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                print("Dispatch")
                AppState.shared.pageToNavigationTo = "test"
            }
            //other required code
        }
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
          options: authOptions,
          completionHandler: { _, _ in }
        )

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        
        FirebaseMessaging.Messaging.messaging().delegate = self //Check why the eroor is getting thown but the code compiles
        
        
    

        
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

ContentsView

```
struct ContentsView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var appState = AppState.shared
    @State var navigate = false
 
    var body: some View {
        
        if (appState.pageToNavigationTo != nil)   {
            HomeView()
        } else {
            
            SearchView()
        }
}
}
```

My logic is if it is triggered by a push notification, then the value of `pageToNavigationTo` won't be nil and a different view will be opened. However, everytime `SearchView()` gets opened. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should walk thru the execution by hand, esp where you set `pageToNavigationTo`. For the purposes of StackOverflow, I find that print statements (and then including the debug output) can help clarify what's going on.

Comment: why do you use `asyncAfter` to set the value? the `ContentView` will likely load before the value is set

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have placed the detection code in the wrong callback handler.  See the function
`func userNotificationCenter(:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  pushexample
//
//  Created by Faisal Memon on 27/02/2023.
//

import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import UserNotifications


class AppState: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AppState()
    
    @Published var launchedFrom: String?
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
            AppState.shared.launchedFrom = "launchedFromMessage"
        }
        
        print(userInfo)
        
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        
        let deviceToken:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
        print("Device token: ", deviceToken) // This token can be used for testing notifications on FCM
    }
}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
            AppState.shared.launchedFrom = "launchedFromMessage"
            
        }
        
        print(userInfo)
        
        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([[.banner, .badge, .sound]])
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        
    }
    
    // app not running
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID from userNotificationCenter didReceive: \(messageID)")
            AppState.shared.launchedFrom = "launchedFromMessage"
        }
        
        print(userInfo)
        
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Note my main UI code is:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct pushexampleApp: App {
    @ObservedObject var state = AppState.shared
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if state.launchedFrom == "launchedFromMessage" {
                MessageLaunchView()
            } else {
                NormalLaunchView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```