# Understanding SwiftUI navigation, with code

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have read the docs but I'm not understanding. Here is the code I have. I removed irrelevant lines.

It works right now. **My question is, how do I programmatically navigate to a ThingDetail screen with a specific Thing passed in?**

When the user receives a notification that says "tap to view this thing", I want them to tap it and then have the app launch to a specific `ThingDetail(thing: thing)`, with a back button that takes them back to the list of all the things.

```
// Home screen is a list of Things that you can tap on to view the ThingDetail screen

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var things: FetchedResults<Thing>
    @State private var navigationPath: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(things) { thing in
                            ThingCard(thing: thing)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Things")
        }
    }
}

// This is a button that has the thing name and metadata, and links to the detail screen
struct ThingCard: View {
    let thing: Thing
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink (destination: ThingDetailView(thing: thing)) {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle()
                Text(thing.value ?? "")
            }
        }
    }
}

// This is the screen that you see when you tap on a ThingCard in the home screen list
struct ThingDetailView: View {
    let thing: Thing
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(thing.value ?? "")
    }
}

extension MyApp: UNCDelegateDelegate {
    func handleUserOpenedNotification(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        // If user tapped notification that said "open to view this thing". I want to show the user a ThingDetail(thing: thing)
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to somehow pass the think on the notification and then append it to the path

Comment: @loremipsum it's ok, I have a solution for that part

Comment: My answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75584199/2715565 is quite similar to this.  You get a push notification, and when you tap it it shows a specific screen instead of the normal screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution, where moving the navigation path and UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to the ObservableObject.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Thing: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var value: String?
}

class NotificationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var navigationPath: NavigationPath = NavigationPath()
    @Published var things = [Thing(value: "Sample1"), Thing(value: "Sample2")]
    
    func get(thing id: String) -> Thing? {
        return things.first(where: { $0.id == id })
    }
}

extension NotificationManager: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        //App is in foreground
        //do whatever you want here, for example:
        navigationPath.append(Thing(value: "All new value"))
        completionHandler([.sound])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        //App is in background, user has tapped on the notification
        //do whatever you want here, for example:
        navigationPath.append(Thing(value: "All new value"))
        completionHandler()
    }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    private let notificationManager = NotificationManager()
    
    init() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = notificationManager
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                ContentView()
                    .environmentObject(notificationManager)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var notificationManager: NotificationManager

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $notificationManager.navigationPath) {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(notificationManager.things) { thing in
                        ThingCard(thing: thing)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Things")
            .navigationDestination(for: Thing.self) { thing in
                ThingDetailView(thing: thing)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ThingCard: View {
    let thing: Thing
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(value: thing) {
            ZStack {
                Text(thing.value ?? "")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ThingDetailView: View {
    let thing: Thing
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(thing.value ?? "")
    }
}
```

## Result :

[image: GIF_description]

Comment: Thanks. I think my first problem is that when I `append` a value like that to `navigationPath` and then `print(navigationPath)` it looks like it's still empty. I added the corresponding `navigationDestination` following your code but no navigation happens. The difference in my code is that `navigationPath` is an `@State` variable

Comment: Use it as a Observable like above it will fix the issue.

Comment: It's working! Whew finally. Does it have to be an environmentObject? Anyways thanks

Comment: You can use it any way you want, the idea is to keep the dependancy attached thats all.

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationLink` now takes a `value` and uses a corresponding `.navigationDestination` modifier (for each value type) when `NavigationStack` was added to iOS 16 in June 2022. This means it is possible for the navigation to stay active when the list is scrolled off the screen, e.g. by a change in a data or if using landscape split view on iPad. Before, when the navigation link scrolled off screen it deactivated and would pop the detail off - a really bad design flaw.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            ForEach(things) { thing in
                 NavigationLink(thing.title, value: thing)
             }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Things")
        .navigationDestination(for: Thing.self) { thing in
             ThingDetail(thing: thing)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't really answer my question. I want to programmatically push a screen to the navigationPath when a user taps a notification